# Pig Writing too many records in a single file

Tags: apache-pig

I am reading a huge file with 4.4 million records. I want to split this into two records with 4 million records and .4 million records based an certain something and then want to store them.

The logic is :

1. Read a huge file with 4.4 million records .
2. Split it into two relations A and B with (1:10 ratio)
3. Union those relations C = Union A, B
4. Store C .

The issue is that C will contain two part-m-* files . One with .4 million records and the other with 4 million records .

Now, the thing is it takes a lot of time to write these files . If I dont do a union and store A and B seperately in two files , will it be faster. I want mappers output to be fast.

For that , we need more mappers and I want mappers output even for a specific relation to be written into multiple files .

Hoow can I ensure this ?